# Module import error while importing train_test_split

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to import the `train_test_split` from `sklearn` by using

```
 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

Every time I am getting the same error saying:

`Module import error, module not found`

I have tried creating a virtual environment in conda and also ran

> conda update -all

I am still getting the same error.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `sklearn` doesn't have `cross_validation`. When did you get this code? Maybe it is old version of `sklearn`.

Comment: documentation shows [sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

By

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```